# Mathematical meaning of "may not"

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

Does "may not" mean that never allowed or sometimes not allowed? For example: the sequence may not converge. Does this mean that the sequence never converges or that there is no guarantee that the sequence converges?

Comment: The mathematical meaning surprisingly coincides with the English meaning.

Comment: The latter. Saying "this-and-this may not happen" means that it is possible that this-and-this happens. In your example, it means that it may not convrege.

Comment: "sometimes not allowed"

Comment: @Silvia that is unhelpful to someone learning English

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry, didn't mean to answer, just pointing out the question is off-topic.

Comment: It is ambiguous without further context.  It could be prescriptive ("You may not go to the movies until your homework is done") or descriptive  ("You may not have time to finish your homework before we go to the movies").

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would strongly recommend avoiding use of "may" altogether when rendering formal mathematical statements into English: use "can" for possibility and "must" for necessity. ("May" suffers from some strange prejudices in its informal use, and as we don't need the "is allowed to" modality for formal mathematical statements, it is best avoided.) This would have avoided the problem in quid's comment on Henning's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In everyday English, the construction "$X$ may not $Y$" can mean either that it is not allowed for $X$ to do $Y$, or that it is possible/conceivable that $X$ does not do $Y$. One needs to look to context and semantics to find out which of these in the case.

In mathematics it is unusual to speak about permission at all -- mathematical objects do whatever they do whether we want them to or not -- so generally the only meaning that makes sense in a mathematical context is that it is possible that $X$ does not do $Y$.

Comment: I disagree with the second paragraph. "Note that we may not interchange the order of limits."

Comment: I agree with quid. Although you are right that mathematical objects "do whatever they do", there are limits of what we can do to them.

Comment: @quid: I'm speaking about the case where the subject of "may not" is a mathematical object. If the subject is something _outside_ mathematics, such as the reader or author of the text, a special mathematical meaning of the phrase of course cannot apply.

Comment: I believe in that situation we are using the "everyday English" version

Comment: This is a published example from a native speaker: "It cannot be zero, for $k$ consecutive terms of the unit sequence may not vanish." The intended meaning is that it is impossible that the terms vanish not that it is possible they do not vanish. The situation is not as clear as this answer suggests.

Comment: Of course, not all native English speakers agree about the language (and some don't use it very well). But to my ear "X may not Y" means that it is possible that X might not Y, but not certain. In line with the usual natural-language English tradition of giving maximal information, it would be unusual, and possibly somewhat misleading,  to say "may not" when "cannot" is actually true.